# How to convert my C# code to a LINQ query?

Tags: c#

I am new to LINQ, I wrote the following code using C#, but I need to rewrite using LINQ. How can I rewrite the same?

Basically, I want to set NULL value for few properties at 0th Index.

Here -  OrganizationList is an array.

```
if (OrganizationList.Count > 0)
{
    if (OrganizationList[0].OrganizationLevel == 0)
    {
        OrganizationList[0].NetworkParticipation = null;
        OrganizationList[0].ApprovalPolicyID = null;
        OrganizationList[0].LastUpdateDate = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't want to use Linq on this. What you have is fine.(Linq is used to select, project, filter, aggregate, etc., *not* mutations. What you have written is the way forward.)

Comment: LINQ: the clue is in the name "Language INtegrated ***Query***". You can use it to choose the things you want to mutate, but it's the wrong tool for making mutations.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that is meaningful. It's clear you need help, or you wouldn't be posting here. It's clear it's C# because you've tagged it as such. That leaves the rest of your title *Link Query*, which is not descriptive of anything. Your title should be clear enough to be of use to a future user of the site who is scanning through a list of search results.

Comment: "all the 0th position in the array": there is only 1 "0th position" in an array.

Comment: You really want linq or what you trying to say is actually lambda expression?

Comment: Thanks Anthony for your valuable input

Comment: Hi Spender, Thanks for looking into my question, Basically its a collection, it has 10 property,in that I need to make only 3 property has NULL for the 1st element in the collection

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite it using LINQ extension methods like this:

```
if (OrganizationList.Any())
{
    var organization = OrganizationList.First();

    if( organization.OrganizationLevel == 0 )
    {
        organization.NetworkParticipation = null;
        organization.ApprovalPolicyID = null;
        organization.LastUpdateDate = null;
    }
}
```

As long as your type is an `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable`, you can apply LINQ to it.
In this example however, there's not too much to gain.  The code might be a bit more readable, but under the covers, the compiler will emit the same IL for this code as for the code in the question

Comment: Thank you so much Frederik for your time and honest response.